# TypeScript allowing extra properties in object assigned to interface extended from another interface [NEXT-AUTH]

Tags: next-auth

I am new to typescript and I am using next auth to build a project I faced this and I do not know why this is happening I checked the next auth files and wrote this question this is not a typescript question since I tried it in a normal ts file and it was working as expected. I am just curious and want an answer to this

**I have this config that is working but it should not**

```
import nextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      credentials: {
        email: {},
        password: {},
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const user = { id: "hello", name: "jay", password: "dave" };
        if (!user || !user.password) return null;

        const passwordsMatch = user.password === credentials?.password;

        if (passwordsMatch) return user;
        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
};

export default nextAuth(authOptions);
```

this is how credentials config interface is defined

```
export interface CredentialsConfig<
  C extends Record<string, CredentialInput> = Record<string, CredentialInput>
> extends CommonProviderOptions {
  type: "credentials"
  credentials: C
  authorize: (
    credentials: Record<keyof C, string> | undefined,
    req: Pick<RequestInternal, "body" | "query" | "headers" | "method">
  ) => Awaitable<User | null>
}
```

as you can see it returns awaitable user and user is defined like this

```
export interface DefaultUser {
  id: string
  name?: string | null
  email?: string | null
  image?: string | null
}

/**
 * The shape of the returned object in the OAuth providers' `profile` callback,
 * available in the `jwt` and `session` callbacks,
 * or the second parameter of the `session` callback, when using a database.
 *
 * [`signIn` callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#sign-in-callback) |
 * [`session` callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback) |
 * [`jwt` callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback) |
 * [`profile` OAuth provider callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers#using-a-custom-provider)
 */
export interface User extends DefaultUser {}
```

awaitable is like this

```
export type Awaitable<T> = T | PromiseLike<T>;
```

as you can see password is not part of User in the interface then why is it working